# Is there a way to find total TLABs allocated in JMC 7.x, like there was in JMC 5.x?

Tags: java, java-11, jfr, java-mission-control

In Java Mission Control 5.x, you could easily view the total size of allocated TLABs. See the "Allocation Summary" in the bottom right of this image.

[image]

In Java Mission Control 7.x, I can't find an easy way to find this high-level information. I can view TLABs in blocks, and get a rough idea of periods of heavy TLAB allocation, but I can't find the total TLABs allocated.
[image: JMC 7.7 TLABs view]

Is there a way in JMC 7.x to view the total size of TLABs allocated during the recording period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Go to the Summary tab on the TLAB Allocations page. You'll need JMC 8.1.0+.

[image]

Comment: So glad they finally brought this back. Thanks.